# Align a div and two images inside of a DIV hortizonally

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to align two images and a DIV. The DIV thats a rounded box keeps ending up beneath the two images.

Here's my HTML/CSS:

```css
.main {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 600px;
  height: 110px;
}

.one {
  float: right;
  height: 100px;
}

.two {
  height: 100px;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.rounded {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-color: #FFF;
  border: 5px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" class="main">
  <div id="one" class="one">
  </div>
  <div id="two" class="two"><img src="[![apple][1]][1]" width="100" height="76" /> <img src="[![titleofpage][1]][1]" width="309" height="61" />
    <div class="box rounded"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I align them all in a straight line in this centered DIV in the middle of the page?

Comment: Can you provide a link to a working example?

Comment: Have a look at using css [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Remove `position:absolute` from the `.box` and add `display:flex` to the `.two` class.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out flexbox:

```css
.flex-container-center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* this is what you need :) */
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container-center">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x50" />
</div>
```

Also, here's a [working example](https://codepen.io/RaysOfTheSun/pen/ebdJoP) and my favorite [guide on flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: flex` and `justify-content: center` to `.two` class;

```
.two {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100px;
}
```

When using `display: flex`, there is a main-axis and cross-axis and you can set the main axis with `flex-direction: row` or `flex-direction: column`. The default is `flex-direction: row` without calling it. This means in the above example the main-axis = row and cross-axis = column.

When centering items using flex box you have two options:

1. `align-items: center`
2. `justify-content: center`

`align-items` controls the cross axis and `justify-content` controls the main axis.

In your example the main axis is row because the `flex-direction` wasn't called, so it used the default row. To center the items on the horizontal axis, you have to use `justify-content`, which uses the main axis (flex-direction) --> row

Answer (score -1):

I tweaked the CSS to use grid view, removed the absolute positions and floats. Added borders so I could see things :)

```
.main{

position: block;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 600px;
height: 110px;
}

.one {
border: 5px solid blue;
height: 100px;
}
.two {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 30%);
height: 100px;
border: 5px solid yellow;
}

.box {
height:50px;
width:50px;

}
.rounded {
border-radius: 10px;
border-color:#FFF;
border: 5px solid red;

}
```